# Using SQL Server full text search, I need result of at least two keywords of subset of keywords, how can it be done?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a database that has big data and I am searching as example of sports subject, I defined subset of keywords that related to sport example.

"club"

"Playground"

"professionalism"

"torsion"

"goal"

Search result must satisfy at least two keywords of keywords above ex. "club" and "playground"  keywords are enough to tell that this row related to sport subject.
I used this query

```
select  count(*) from datatable 
where contains (body,'("club" And "Playground") 
       or ("club" and "professionalism") 
       or ("club" and "torsion")  
       or ("club" and "goal") or .... or all probablities')
```

and also I used:

```
 select  count(*) 
 from datatable 
 where 
  contains (body,'"Playground" OR "professionalism" OR "torsion" OR "goal"')
   And contains(body,'"club"  OR "professionalism" OR "torsion" OR "goal"') 
   And contains(body,'"club" OR "Playground" OR "torsion" OR "goal"') 
   And contains(body,'"club" OR "Playground" OR "professionalism" OR "goal"') 
   And contains(body,'"club" OR "Playground" OR "professionalism" OR "torsion"' )
```

but both are so slow

what is the best practise for this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure the second example makes that much sense. Does it actually bring back the correct results? Will the first example also double count if one contains 3 of the 5 names?

Comment: second query in every contains , one keyword missed

Comment: Since you are looking at exact matches (double-quotes) and not really taking advantage of all that CONTAINS can do, have you considered using sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-by-document-transact-sql)? Depending on the permissions and your actual use cases, it might be possible to do something with that. (Or, if you only need approximate answers, not exact answers, you could work with sys.dm_fts_index_keywords, with the same caveats).

Answer (score 0):

Although I doubt it would be faster, I am curious if you have tried something like the following to avoid listing all the combinations. If the performance isn't worse, I think it's probably easier to add/charge words with something based on this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
 SELECT datatable_pkey
 FROM
 (
   SELECT datatable_pkey
   FROM datatable
   WHERE contains (body, '"club"')
  UNION ALL
   SELECT datatable_pkey
   FROM datatable
   WHERE contains (body, '"Playground"')
  UNION ALL
   SELECT datatable_pkey
   FROM datatable
   WHERE contains (body, '"professionalism"')
  UNION ALL
   SELECT datatable_pkey
   FROM datatable
   WHERE contains (body, '"torsion"')
  UNION ALL
   SELECT datatable_pkey
   FROM datatable
   WHERE contains (body, '"goal"')
 ) a
 GROUP BY datatable_pkey
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time , i used this query before .it takes the same time , slow paging data to client cause selecting all data then paging.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't expect it to be faster, but I was hoping it might be about the same speed if the DB realized it could optimize.